# Wordpress urls not working after live version

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Dear Stackoverflowers,

I just moved a wordpress site I was developing on my localmachine to a digital ocean droplet.

You can see the result on https://bouwman.me

The homepage / is working, and when I set the permalinks to default it also works. But I want the permalinks to be: https://bouwman.me/2016/06/23/example-post/

My .htaccess is the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I know this is a common problem, but I can't fix it.

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Theo

Comment: Did you change your permalinks accordingly in the admin section to match that format?

Comment: Check if apache `mod_rewrite` has been enabled. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: When you migrated, did you do a URL string replace too?

Comment: @Aibrean Yes, in the config file

Comment: The config file doesn't always work. DB string replace is the best method.WP Migrate DB has that integrated in it.

Comment: @Aibrean I installed WP Migrate BD and migrated is. But it didn't work.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden that didn't fixed my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I recommend if you don't have anything defined by yourself in your .htaccess file.

1. Remove .htaccess file
2. Use wordpress admin pages and save your permalinks setup. Wordpress will write a new .htaccess file correctly.
3. Ensure that your web server is configured correctly. Specifically, check mod rewrite is enabled (as the current 404 page indicates apache httpd web server)

I do this all the time when migrating a site from one server to another.

Comment: What didn't work? did the .htaccess file not get written? did it get written incorrectly? or did it get written correctly but wordpress is not honoring it?

Comment: The last one is the problem

Comment: I modified my answer, to include checking web server configuration.

Comment: Yes it is enabled. But nothing changed.